# Swift's standard library and name collision

Tags: namespaces, swift, naming-conventions, naming, standard-library

I know that Swift doesn't use namespaces, but that names are defined within each module. First of all, I don't understand very well how this avoids name collisions -feel free to elaborate.

Nevertheless, my main question is: Let's say I want a tree structure without using NSTreeNode, so I make my own class named "TreeNode". Now let's say that Apple decides to include a class to build trees in Swift's standard library, and, as expected, they name it "TreeNode". What happens then? My custom TreeNode will collide with Standard Library's TreeNode... Will I have to change all my code in cases like that? Or maybe Apple will promise that Swift's Standard Library will not change in the future?

EDIT: Question answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24293236/3463265) (thanks @Martin R for your comment)

Comment: Does this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24002821/how-do-you-use-namespaces-in-swift answer your question ?

Comment: @MartinR No, it doesn't answer my question. Or if it does, I don't understand it. Nested types are not applicable for this issue. The "modules" thing; I still don't get it. But in the case of my TreeNode example, I don't think modules help, because the Standard Library is everywhere. Thanks for your comment, though.

Comment: Have a look at matt's answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/24293236/1187415. - In your case it would be TreeNode and Swift.TreeNode.

Comment: Oh! I saw that question before writing mine, but I overlooked this answer. Sorry for that. This one seems to address my question, but not fully: it doesn't say if this is applicable for the Standard Library, nor how. -This is easy to check, though: I'll just try writing a custom "Array" class and see what the compiler says. Many thanks!

Answer (score 36):

Namespacing in Swift is implicit. All classes and other symbols belong to the target (module) they are defined in. So if you define a class `String` the fully qualified name would be `MyTarget.String`. When there is a name collision, you have to prefix the class name with the module (framework) it is defined in, except when there is a class with that name defined in the current module - this class takes precedence and does not need to be prefixed.

```
struct String {
    var swiftString = ""
}

var a = String()
var b = Swift.String()
```

So if you create your class `TreeNode` and Apple later adds a `TreeNode` as well, your name would take precedence if you are using only one module and you wouldn't need to change anything. If you would want to use Swift's `TreeNode`, you would need to refer to it as `Swift.TreeNode`.