# Swift Ambiguous reference to member

Tags: ios, swift, jwt

I am using https://github.com/kylef/JSONWebToken.swift package for handling encoding and decoding of JWT.

I am on Swfit 3 and xcode 8.0.1. The problem that I am having is, after importing JWT into my controller file, when I call

```
JWT.encode(claims: ["my": "payload"], algorithm: .hs256("secret".data(using: .utf8)!))
```

The compiler complains:

> Ambiguous reference to member 'encode(_:algorithm)'.

I then pressed command + click on the JWT.encode method and traced the method down and found out that the JWT.encode method actually referencing to the .encode method in MultipartFormData.swift of Alamofire.

I have imported both JWT and Alamofire.

Basically, the JWT and Alamofire MultipartFormData.swift both have a public method called encode, and I am calling it explicitly JWT.encode, why would it refer to the encode method in the Foundation library?

How should I fix it?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Did you try to prefix the method name with the module? It should work according to this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/25232124/250164

---

**EDIT:** I think I figured it out. Your function signature is wrong, hence the encode method cannot be found. Use the following code instead, this seems to work for me:

```
JWT.encode(["my": "payload"], algorithm: .hs256("secret".data(using: .utf8)!))
```

Comment: I am calling it by JWT.encode(). Is that what you mean?

Comment: Perhaps it would be something like JWT.JWT.encode(). I would assume JWT is the module which contains a class JWT which has a method called encode. Something like that.

Comment: Well. I have almost tried almost all possibilities but it didn't work.

Comment: Check the edit. I think I've found your fix by creating a small test project. If you still have an issue, I'll upload my test project to my GitHub for you to verify.