# Swift Namespacing Issue

Tags: swift, namespaces

I have created a class named `Bundle`, which I'd really like to remain named that way, as it perfectly describes what it's for in my project.
Now, I'm using Swift's `Bundle` in some code and now those names are conflicting. I had this issue before when I created the class `Set`. I was able to solve that by putting `Swift.Set` when I wanted to use the standard `Set` class, as I found in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25232124/3397217) on exactly this matter.
I also tried to apply that solution my `Bundle` problem, but Xcode complains:

> Module 'Swift' has no member named 'Bundle'

Any idea why it does work for `Set`, but not `Bundle`?
Thanks!

Comment: I would *really* consider renaming *your* class ...

Comment: I'm always trying to improve my coding style. Why would you *really* suggest renaming it?

Comment: Just my (spontaneous, personal) opinion. Avoiding the name collision seems less confusing  to me in the long run. What if a new developer works on your project, and does not know that there are different Bundle classes?

Comment: That certainly is an argument. However, 1) the error will let him know and 2) I'm trying really hard to document well, so that anyone can get started working on it, without any prior knowledge of my project.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`Bundle`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/bundle) is defined in the Foundation library, not in the Swift standard
library:

```
let mainBundle = Foundation.Bundle.main
```