# How can I disambiguate my type from a module type

Tags: swift

I am having troubles referring to a symbol from 3rd party module, my code looks something like this:

```
import Foo // 3rd party module

struct Foo { // my type on my module
    //...
}

struct Bar: Foo.ProtocolA { // here swift referes to my struct instead of the module
    
}
```

I cannot only use `: ProtocolA` because that name is already being used in my module.

Is there a way to disambiguate this?

I have seen similar questions but they solve different thing, disambiguating a module type instead of own type.

TIA

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Swift's standard library and name collision](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25231650/swifts-standard-library-and-name-collision)

Comment: Unfortunately it doesnt. I have updated my question to make it more clear, thanks anyways

Answer (score 1):

You can fix this by importing the submodules from the parent module directly; e.g. in your example that would become something like:

```
import protocol Foo.ProtocolA
```

You can specify many types to import, like class enum let/var etc. as well, not only a protocol.

The obvious downside is that the amount of imports can balloon quickly if you need a lot of submodules from the specific parent module.
Personally I usually try to avoid naming collisions altogether, sometimes at the expensive of slightly less descriptive naming while still being understandable. Additionally as far as I know there is no way to alias imports at this time in Swift.

Comment: I tried to do that, but when I want to conform to the protocol it will still refer to my struct. I tried to alias it (yes, it is possible :D) with `typealias Something = Foo.ProtocolA` and didnt work either

Comment: Thats not what i meant with aliasing; for instanec "import Foo as Foo2" would be aliasing as I meant it. anyway if the import above does not properly make "ProtocolA" available in your codebase than that sounds like a compiler bug you should file.