# Firebase authentication in SwiftUI

Tags: swift, firebase, swiftui, firebase-authentication

i looked at solutions for firebase authentication online and on here. I haven't found a solution to implement a listener for firebase authentication.

Older solutions use the following code for a listener. i used it and gives an error.

- cannot assign the value of type 'User.Type' to the User.

//Below is the following code i used for the listener

```
func listen() {
   handle = Auth.auth().addStateDidChangeListener({ (auth, user) in
   if let user = user {
      self.session = User
   } else {
     self.session = nil
            }
        })
    }
```

//this is the user model below

```
struct User {
    var uid: String
    var email: String
}
```

Comment: Just write "self.session = user" instead of "self.session = User"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you'd like to use your own `User` model like this (as opposed to using the `User` object that Firebase provides), you could do this:

```
func listen() {
        handle = Auth.auth().addStateDidChangeListener({ (auth, user) in
            if let user = user {
                self.session = User(uid: user.uid, email: user.email ?? "") //the ?? "" provides a default value in case the email provided by Firebase is nil
            } else {
                self.session = nil
            }
        })
}
```

However, it might be easier to get rid of your own `User` model code and just use the one that Firebase provides. So, once you've deleted your `struct User { }` code, you could just do this:

```
func listen() {
        handle = Auth.auth().addStateDidChangeListener({ (auth, user) in
            if let user = user {
                self.session = user
            } else {
                self.session = nil
            }
        })
}
```

---

Since your app *and* Firebase both provide `User` objects, you may run into namespace collisions (where two types share the same name) unless you change the name of your `User` struct (or, implement the second suggestion I gave). See:
[Swift's standard library and name collision](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25231650/swifts-standard-library-and-name-collision)

Answer (score 1):

You could do it like this in your ViewModel:

```
@Published var session = UserModel()

func listenAuth() {
    listenerAuth = Auth.auth().addStateDidChangeListener { (auth, user) in
        if let user = user {
            self.session = UserModel(uid: user.uid, email: user.email ?? "")
        } else {
          self.session = nil
        }
    }
}
```