# Is putting your class inside a struct an acceptable way to namespace your class in Swift?

Tags: swift

Is putting your class inside a struct an acceptable way to namespace your class in Swift? I did not see any mention of nested struct or struct-class in the programming guide.

```
struct TestNamespace {
    class Test {

    }
}
```

Comment: "Acceptable" is a loosely define term and subject to debates. See: http://stackoverflow.com/q/24002821/how-do-you-use-namespaces-in-swift

Comment: Why do you want to namespace your class? Isn't the module namespace enough? A real example might help us figure out if there may be a better solution.

Comment: Using dynamic frameworks (iOS 8+) all classes belong to their module namespace.

Answer (score 0):

I'd be (even more) happy *with* namespaces in Swift, because they help organize the code more granularly. If you're experimenting with using `struct` as a namespace, consider disabling its construction:

```
struct PseudoNamespace {

    private init() {}

    //...

}
```

Using `struct` has an advantage over using `class`: structs does not support inheritance and with classes it needs using `final` modifier.

One significant disadvantage of this emulation is that there is no way no "import" such a namespace (like `import PseudoNamespace.*`, etc.), because Swift allows importing modules, but not structs.

Comment: No way to import because of private init or struct?

Comment: Private `init` only denies construction. Swift allows importing _modules_, but `struct` is not a module, so the language does not allow to import it. You'll always need to type the struct name to address the nested items, like `PseudoNamespace.NestedClass`.