# Swift dynamic type Debug/Release

Tags: ios, swift, compiler-optimization

I've this piece of code:

```
class NotificationsController: NSObject {

    static var classNotifier: AnyClass {
        if #available(iOS 10, *) {
            return UNUserNotificationCenter.classForCoder()
        } else {
            return UILocalNotification.classForCoder()
        }
    }

    static func foo() {
        NotificationsController.classNotifier.foo()
    }

}
```

Where:

```
protocol Notificable: class {
   static func foo()
}

extension UNUserNotificationCenter: Notificable {

   static func foo() {
      // do something
   }

}

extension UILocalNotification: Notificable {

   static func foo() {
      // do something
   }

}
```

Building in Debug mode works fine.
When I build in Release mode (for archiving), compiler says that AnyClass have not a function called "foo".

Now, I know that if I remove Release optimizations build works, but I think would be the wrong solution.

Other solutions?

Comment: `classNotifier` returns a `Class` but `foo` is an instance method, right? Also, I would probably call your protocol `Notifiable` instead.

Comment: Have you tried `(NotificationsController.classNotifier as AnyObject).foo()`?

Comment: Have you tried to make foo in the protocol Notificable to static like static func foo ?

Comment: shouldn't it be `static var classNotifier: Notificable` in `NotificationsController`

Comment: Check out this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/36577441/1607485

Answer (score 0):

After some time I do investigation of the code and rewrite you're solution. Problem is connected with `protocol Notificable` and instance function `func foo()`.

You try to call this function as class function not instance one and there is a problem.

Example of the working solution.

```
protocol Notificable: class {
     static func foo()
}

extension UNUserNotificationCenter: Notificable {
    internal static func foo() {

    }
}

extension UILocalNotification: Notificable {
    internal static func foo() {

    }
}

class NotificationsController: NSObject {

    static var classNotifier: AnyClass {
        if #available(iOS 10, *) {
            return UNUserNotificationCenter.classForCoder()
        } else {
            return UILocalNotification.classForCoder()
        }
    }

    static func foo() {
        classNotifier.foo()
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks oleg for the point. Actually is my mistake, in real code I already have static methods (I update question). Problem still remains

Comment: @LucaDavanzo NotificationsController and Extensions are in different files?

Comment: Try to put all this information to one class and try to build.