# Extend Private class defined in an extension of class in Swift

Tags: swift

## TL;DR

Is it possible to extend a privately owned and defined-in-extension class, i.e. `NewsParser`?

---

**Related documents**

[swift2 - Extension of a nested type in Swift - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35673290/extension-of-a-nested-type-in-swift) talks about similar situation, except the nested class type is not private.

---

I have a class `NewsPost`:

```
class NewsPost {
  var title: String?
  var author: String?
  var mainContent: NSAttributedString?

  var data: Data? {
    didSet {
      let newsParser = NewsParser(delegate: self)
      newsParser.parse()
    }
  }

  // Init methods and other stuff...
}
```

And a `NewsPost`-owned class `NewsParser`: (in another Swift file, but this does not seem to be a factor, due to [SR-631](https://bugs.swift.org/browse/SR-631))

```
private extension NewsPost {
  private class NewsParser {
    weak var delegate: NewsPost?
    // Other properties for parsing...

    init(delegate: NewsPost) {
      self.delegate = delegate
    }

    func parse() {
      // parse the delegate.data and update properties in delegate (NewsPost instance)
    }

    // Other methods to be called for parsing...
  }
}
```

---

## But it does not seem to possible to extend `NewsPost.NewsParser`.

The following attempts do not work:

#### Attempt 1

> Error: 'NewsParser' is inaccessible due to 'fileprivate' protection level

```
private extension NewsPost { // Notice the "private" prefix
  class NewsParser {
    weak var delegate: NewsPost?
    //Other properties for parsing...

    init(delegate: NewsPost) {
      self.delegate = delegate
    }

    func parse() {
      // parse the delegate.data and update properties in delegate (NewsPost instance)
    }
    // Other methods to be called for parsing...
  }
}
```

Error happens in `NewsPost` definition:

```
var data: Data? {
    didSet {
        let newsParser = NewsParser(delegate: self) // error happens here
        newsParser.parse()
    }
}
```

#### Attempt 2

> Error: 'NewsParser' is inaccessible due to 'private' protection level

```
extension NewsPost { 
    private class NewsParser { // Notice the "private" prefix
        var delegate: NewsPost
        // Other properties for parsing...

        func parse() {
            // parse the delegate.data and update properties in delegate (NewsPost instance)
        }

        // Other methods to be called for parsing...
    }
}

extension NewsPost.NewsParser { // error happens here
// extensions here...
// many kinds of errors happen here
}
```

---

**Is it possible to extend a privately owned and defined-in-extension class, i.e. `NewsParser`?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried your code in a playground and it worked like a charm with a private class nested in a private extension :

Called that way :

```
var str = "Hello, playground"
let post = NewsPost()
post.data = str.data(using: .utf8)
```

[image]

Your main problem is that your probably declared your *private* extension in a separate file and *private* means *fileprivate* for an extension. Put your extension and your `NewsPost`class in the same file and your error should go away!

If you really want to extend `NewsParser` you **have to** make it internal.
Extension declaration are only valid at file scope so if you create a private class you have no way of extending it.

Note that an internal nested class would not be visible outside its target. So using Frameworks you should be able to hide your `NewsParser` class from your UI code.

Comment: Sorry I only saw your **Edit** on your answer now. I am now changing `NewsParser` to be `internal`.

Comment: Could you edit your answer post to highlight the last two paragraphs? It would help other viewers of this question.

Comment: The answer does not change, if the class is private you simply can't extend it. And if you want to have a private extension (fileprivate) you have to use it in the same file

Comment: What are the differences between `private extension { class NewsParser { ... } } ` and `extension { class NewsParser { ... } }`?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/180997/discussion-between-jackxujh-and-andercover).